# How to parallelize properly dataflow job over 11M of files stored on GCS using fileio.MatchFiles(file_pattern = 'gs://bucket/**/*')

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, glob

I have a beginner question. I have ~11millions files stored on some GCS bucket with the following structure in a given bucket:

yyyy/mm/dd

I have 6 years of data with ~1500 files per years.

```
    lines = (p
     | "ReadInputData" >> fileio.MatchFiles(file_pattern = 'gs://bucket/**/*')  
     | "FileToBytes" >> fileio.ReadMatches()
     | "Reshuffle" >> beam.Reshuffle()
     | "GetMetada" >> beam.Map(lambda file: post_process(file))
     | "WriteTableToBQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(...)
    )
```

For each files, I am checking the metadata (extension, size, ...), then for PDF files I open it to check the number of pages. For images, I compute some hash. This is is the `post_process()` python function.

The current dataflow is running since 3 days (which is quite a lot) but it is not parallelized properly since most of the time 1 vCPU is used:
[image]

It seems that the job search for the file for very long time with 1 worker (vCPU) then for the processing to to ~25 workers for ~10 min and continue like that for days. I am doing something wrong.

Before I did some test for a month(144'000 files) with `file_pattern = 'gs://bucket/2022/04/**/*'`
I went from 4h (only one workers was used ) to 16 min (scale up to 57 workers) by adding `"Reshuffle" >> beam.Reshuffle()` which was missing.

[image]

I am using python, `Apache Beam Python 3.9 SDK 2.40.0`, I use Dataflow template with a container(`--sdk_container_image` option).

My question is how to use properly `fileio.MatchFiles(file_pattern = 'gs://bucket/**/*')` to have it using multiple workers all the time. It seems that what I did works for `file_pattern = 'gs://bucket/2022/04/**/*'` but not for `file_pattern = 'gs://bucket/**/*'`. What is the best practice ? Didn't find something that could answer my question in the documentation. If I do a loop over year and month I don't know if this will be properly parallelized and if this is the right things to do. Any suggestion, recommendation ? Thanks

edit 1:

I found that looping over the years give better results

```
for year in range(2017, 2023):
     list_yyyy_mm.append( p | f"MatchFile {year:04d}" >> fileio.MatchFiles(file_pattern = f"gs://bucket/{year:04d}/**/*"))

files = (
    list_yyyy_mm
    | "Flatten" >> beam.Flatten()
    p
    ...
    )
```

Now I can process the 6 years of data in ~2 hours which is much better.
[image]
This is not well parallelized as it takes ~30 min with 5 workers to list the 12 millions of files. Later the reading the 12 millions of files and the extraction of the metadata is working as expected. Last part is limited to ~230 workers because I don't have enough IP but this is an issue on my side).

I tried to loop over years and months but it is even worse.

Not sure is this is expected for `fileio.MatchFiles` or if I should write my own version and optimize it for my use case. Maybe this is documented but I didn't find it.

Comment: The Beam/Dataflow team is aware that with a lot of file the current implementation is not optimal and they are working on improving it https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/20137#issuecomment-1324331946